# JQuery post does not work issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I  have the following 2 files :

```
<?php

?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function () {
        var textu = $("#textu").val();
        $.post("index.php", function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
<script>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="textu" name="textu">
    <input type="submit" value="send" id="send">
</form>
```

Now I want to style the data that it's returned from the `index.php` where I sent the values.

The problem is that if I use something like `<h1>` or any html tag in the file `index.php` the test file will just return it as plain text for example `<h1>text</h1>`.

I want to style the data that comes from `index.php` but I can't manage to do it because it keeps returning me the plain text and I can't use any html tags or anything apart from PHP in that file. How can I do that ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Add datatype `html` as third parameter to `$.post` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post("index.php", function (data) {
    alert(data);
}, 'html');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

html

```
<input type="text" id="textu" name="textu">
<input value="send" id="send">
```

jQuery:

```
$("#send").click(function(){
  var textu = $("#textu").val();
  $.post("index.php",{"textu":textu},function(data){
     alert(data);
  });
});
```